# The Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)

Tags: script, greasemonkey, chrome-extensions, tampermonkey

[image]

The [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) is a project to collect various minor client-side bug fixes, work-arounds and usability improvements for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and other Q&A sites on the [Stack Exchange Network](https://stackexchange.com/) into a single user script.

The intent of SOUP is not to make any substantial or controversial changes to the Stack Exchange user interface, but to fix minor problems and omissions that the SE developers have overlooked or haven't got around to fixing yet.  By combining these minor patches into a single user script, they become easier to install and maintain.

### Installing

SOUP can be installed either as a stand-alone browser extension or via a user script manager such as [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/), [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) or [Violentmonkey](https://violentmonkey.github.io/about/).

SOUP has been mainly developed and tested on Firefox and Chrome.  It may also run on other browsers with user script support (via Tampermonkey or other compatible extensions), but has not been fully tested on them.  Any reports of cross-browser issues are welcome.

#### Installing as a browser extension

Users of Chrome or Firefox (including Firefox Mobile) can install SOUP as a browser extension:

- [**SOUP on Firefox Add-ons**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/so-unofficial-patch-soup/)
- [**SOUP on Chrome Web Store**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-overflow-unofficial/bagdnnmjfkaolcegcgeohpboeocfalpj)

Note that updates to the extension packages available at Firefox Add-ons and Chrome Web Store may take a few days to appear, even after a new stable user script version is released, due to review and other delays.

#### Installing as a user script

To install SOUP as a user script, you first need to install a  user script manager such as [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (for Firefox), [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) or [Violentmonkey](https://violentmonkey.github.io/about/).  (Other Greasemonkey compatible user script managers should also work.)  After installing the extension, clicking the ["download / install"](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/raw/master/SOUP.user.js) button below should bring up a dialog asking you if you want to install SOUP.  Answer "yes".

> #### [<kbd>Download / Install SOUP</kbd>](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/raw/master/SOUP.user.js)
>
> <sup>[View source](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/master/SOUP.user.js) / [List of fixes](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/master/CONTENTS.md) / [Change log](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) / [GitHub repo](https://github.com/vyznev/soup)</sup>
>
> <sup>NOTE: Tampermonkey on Chrome may suffer from [a race condition](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/211) that can cause some fixes that rely on early loading to fail to apply properly.  To avoid this, you should either use the stand-alone [SOUP Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-overflow-unofficial/bagdnnmjfkaolcegcgeohpboeocfalpj) or set Inject Mode to "Instant" in Tampermonkey preferences (in the Experimental section, only visible when Config Mode is set to "Advanced" above).  Other user script managers on Chrome may also be subject to similar issues.</sup>

#### Installing the development version

If you like living on the edge, you can also install the development version of SOUP, which gets all the latest fixes and updates as soon as they're written.  Of course, it also gets all the latest bugs, too.  If you do install the development version, please report any bugs or regressions you may find in it below!

> #### [<kbd>Download / Install SOUP (development branch)</kbd>](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/raw/devel/SOUP.user.js)
>
> <sup>[View source](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/devel/SOUP.user.js) / [List of fixes](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/devel/CONTENTS.md) / [Change log](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/devel/CHANGELOG.md) / [GitHub repo](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/tree/devel)</sup>

Note that the development version of SOUP is currently only available as a user script.

### Included fixes

The list of issues fixed by the latest version of SOUP is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/master/CONTENTS.md) (also [for the development branch](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/devel/CONTENTS.md)).  You can also browse the [change log](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) ([development](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/devel/CHANGELOG.md)) to see which fixes have been added and removed in recent versions of SOUP.

### License

SOUP is distributed under the [ISC license](https://opensource.org/licenses/ISC), a permissive BSD-style open source license.

In addition, permission is given to Stack Exchange, Inc. to make use of SOUP code in any way they see fit, including but not limited to incorporating all or parts of it within the Stack Exchange codebase, with or without credit.

SOUP includes a copy of the [punycode.js](https://mths.be/punycode) library v1.2.4 by [Mathias Bynens](https://mathiasbynens.be/), distributed under the [MIT license](https://opensource.org/licenses/ISC).  The additional permissions granted above do not apply to this library.

### Credits

SOUP is currently maintained by [Ilmari Karonen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/174699/ilmari-karonen).  Some of the fixes are based on suggestions or earlier user scripts made by others; see the [source code](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/master/SOUP.user.js) and/or the meta.SO links above for details.

### Contributing

If you know a user script or stylesheet patch for SO or other SE sites that would be suitable for inclusion in SOUP, or an unfixed issue that you believe might be worth patching, please let me know (e.g. by posting a comment or an answer the [SOUP page on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch)).

If you'd like to help me out by contributing new fixes directly to SOUP, the [SOUP wiki on GitHub](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/wiki) has some useful tips.  Any and all contributions will be appreciated!

### See also

- [SE Chat Modifications — Keyboard navigation and commands for chat](https://stackapps.com/questions/2105/se-chat-modifications-keyboard-navigation-and-commands-for-chat)
- [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/q/6091)
- ...and other [popular user scripts on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts)

Comment: After I install it, I can't see what have changed. Do we have a GUI panel so that I can turn on and off features?

Comment: No, there currently isn't any control panel. I've thought of having one, and the code is structured to sort of support it, but so far it's been a fairly low priority for me. If you're just curious and want to see what the different fixes do, you can always click the links above: most of the linked bug reports / feature requests include instructions for reproducing the bug. Try it with SOUP on and off, and compare the behavior. (And if you find some cases where there no longer is any difference, please do tell me; it's been a while since I last did that myself.)

Comment: Wow, i just have dug your GitHub and very impressed that you maintain and even write wikis. Have you think about make a Trello board for easier to maintain the script? [An example of HabitRPG using Trello](https://trello.com/b/EpoYEYod/habitrpg)

Comment: I was thinking about promoting your awesome work using Community Ads. [What do you think?](http://imgur.com/Bikmvtw)

Comment: (Fonts, colors and text are open for discussion. I guess I'll recreate it with Inkscape instead of GIMP to get the alignments right.)

Comment: @Raphael: That's... pretty awesome. :o

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I'm glad you like it! I'll start using this then, and maybe update later. If you have any wishes regarding the design, please let me know! (You may obviously use it yourself, too. I can send you the XCF if you want.)

Comment: I've made the pull request [Chrome extension support](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/pull/26) that adds Chrome extension support. Also added a hidden install message in the footer.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11392/mathjax-preview-broken-when-equations-contain-labels#comment91092_11392 is fixed natively now

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: Thanks for the heads-up. The SOUP fix will be removed in the next stable version (which I really should release soon... trying to get the Chrome / Firefox extensions to their proper distribution channels has been one source of delay, although not the only one).

Comment: Is this still being worked on?

Comment: @SirCumference: Yes, although not nearly as actively as I used to. As a not-so-subtle hint, if you find a problem with SOUP or if you'd like to suggest a new fix to be included, you can submit [bug reports and suggestions for new features](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/issues) and even [contribute code](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/pulls) to SOUP at GitHub. :)

Comment: "[*mse143973: Images can be pushed outside the boundaries of a post by using nested lists*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143973)" This has been marked as status completed, so the functionality can be removed.

Comment: After installing, "Options" is greyed out. I don't know how else to actually *use* this extension.

Comment: @pkamb: The are no configurable options, it should "just work". If you want to see what it's doing, a lot of the bug reports / feature requests linked from the [list of included fixes](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/master/CONTENTS.md) include examples of things that work better with SOUP installed. (As a disclaimer, I've been kind of busy with other things lately, and I know there are several fixes in the current version of SOUP that either need updating to work properly or should be removed entirely because the bug they work around was fixed by SE. I really should update SOUP soon.)

Comment: Oh, I was expecting configurable display options such as being able to hide the Hot Network Questions sidebar and hide the "Welcome back!" message. The greyed out "Options" button in the menu makes me think that there are options but that the extension is misconfigured.

Comment: @pkamb: You might be mistaking SOUP for [SOX](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox). Anyway, I'd hide that "options" button if I could, but I don't know if that's even possible.

Comment: Where is the list of changes contained in the script. It's really not obvious what exactly does it do.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica: See the "Included fixes" section above. Or just [follow this link](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/master/CONTENTS.md).

Answer (score 12):

## Feature requests

> **Know a fix that should be included in SOUP (or an issue that could be fixed)?  List it here.**

#### Future plans

Plans for the long-term future of SOUP 2.0:

- Break up the monolithic SOUP.user.js file into multiple files, separating the actual fixes from the framework and metadata.  Use a (Perl?) build script to assemble the pieces into the actual (minified?) user script file.
- Create a UI to allow individual fixes to be toggled on and off at will (and maybe allow user-tweakable parameters for fixes)?

#### Possible additions

These issues might be fixed in a future SOUP 1.x release, but need some work first:

- Apply the [mse234680 punycode fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234680) also to URLs pasted directly into the editor.  Needs a back-end method to reliably detect and process pasted text.
- Improved fixes for [MathJax preview broken when equations contain `\label`s](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11392) and [Turn off MathJax noErrors extension during preview](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12512)
- [Make Stack Exchange sites compatible to OS X Lion full screen mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/113212): This should be easy enough to fix, but I'd need to find a Mac to reproduce it on first.
- [Feature request: user script or option to turn off instant MathJax rendering](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2558) (MathJax): Might be worth it, even though it means adding an extra UI element.
- [Any chance of MathJax in chat?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/97938) (MathJax, chat): Probably too major a change for SOUP, plus limited utility unless enabled for *all* users.  Instead, I've written [a separate user script](https://github.com/vyznev/chatjax) (currently dependent on SOUP) for this.  See [Google Chrome Chat MathJax Extension](https://stackapps.com/questions/4370/google-chrome-chat-mathjax-extension) and [ChatJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support/3297#3297) for alternative implementations.
- [Ability to minimize oneboxes in chat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/203302/174699) (chat): Has existing userscript fixes by C5H8NNaO4 and DaveRandom. Could be a useful addition to SOUP, if it's not too complicated.
- [Shouldn't downvoted answers on meta be non-transparent instead of semi-transparent?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/142628): Closely related to the existing [mso129593](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/129593) fix (and somewhat redundant to it).  Would be simple to do, but some people might not really want it(?).
- [Visited questions are practically indistinguishable in search results](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12902/9602) (math.SE only): Really two bugs in one: search results lack question/answer-hyperlink classes, and math.SE link colors are generally messed up.

#### Declined:

These issues are out of scope for SOUP, or cannot be easily fixed:

- [LaTeX in post preview is slow](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222/latex-in-post-preview-is-slow) (MathJax): Probably too difficult to fix reliably; could reconsider if it turns out not to be.  See [A prototype for incremental preview updates](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4208/a-prototype-for-incremental-preview-updates) for an existing user script that attempts this, and [Feature request: user script or option to turn off instant MathJax rendering](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2558) for an alternative workaround.
- [Viewing single answers in math-heavy threads takes too long](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/538) (MathJax): The fix itself is actually quite easy (just set the `elements` option in MathJax config), but it does no good — typesetting the rest of the page causes the text to jump up and down so much that you still have to wait for it to finish before you can actually read anything.  Seems effectively unfixable. :-(

#### Proposed:

Feel free to add new proposals here.

- [Show Area 51 rep with Area 51 Discussions rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291748/show-area-51-rep-with-area-51-discussions-rep)

Comment: @DavideCervone: Thanks! Has the "disable noerrors extension while editing" thing even been feature-requested on meta? And if not, would you mind doing that so I'll have a request to link to?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, OK, I've posted [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12512/turn-off-mathjax-noerrors-extension-during-preview) concerning the noErrors extension.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, you may also want to call your MathJax reset function (I forget the exact name) in the Begin Process message handler, so that the definitions will be reset for each typeset pass (i.e., the definitions from the previous typeset will not be in effect for the next typeset).

Comment: @DavideCervone: I already do that. However, I just realized that my earlier code had a race condition bug: it would break if the begingroup extension didn't get loaded before the initial typeset pass began. This never seemed to happen on Chrome, but it happens very often in Firefox. [I've fixed it now, though.](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/commit/e724c74ec96fa36467a0cf3214b548ef0fa84b73)

Comment: @DavideCervone: Also, I got your fixes working in the devel branch, but I have something slightly more ambitious yet in mind: making `\label`s in separate posts completely independent of each other. I think I know how to do this (it involves changing the `formatID` function), but the race condition bug mentioned above messed up my testing of it yesterday.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, nice solution to the begingroup issue.  I'll be interested in your solution to the label problem.

Comment: @DavideCervone: Just FYI, I've been a bit slow with getting the improved `\label` fix done, so decided to just release SOUP v1.4 with your original fixes. I'm planning to get the improved fix done for v1.6.

Comment: I had this idea for the new Android app but it applies to the browser version of SE, too. Is it possible to disable the preemptive compilation MathJax does and instead compile only when the user clicks on a piece of math? (On my Mini PC with an Atom Dxxx, long math-heady posts load a *long* time.) I guess that won't be exactly "consensus" for this here fix, but it may be an option for the proposed turning-off feature (with GUI?).

Comment: @Raphael: That is doable, yes. (The trick is to use `@run-at document-start` to inject a custom MathJax config script before MathJax loads, just like SOUP does for the `\newcommand` fix.) It not something I'd consider suitable for SOUP, but I'll add it to my list of possible ideas for new user scripts. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if that's feasible, but [moving discussions to chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93444/provide-a-tool-for-moderators-to-migrate-comments-to-chat) would be great. The script would have to a) create a new chatroom, b) copy (selected) comments there and c) delete comments.

Comment: @Raphael: Unless there's some way to hook into the existing comment migration feature (and I kind of doubt it, since it seems like it'd be a security hole), step c would have to be mod-only. And I'm not a mod on any SE site, so I can't really develop and test it myself. (There was [one mod-only fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160338/allow-moderators-to-reply-to-a-flag) in SOUP once, but it was mostly developed by Manishearth, who *is* a mod.) That said, if somebody does come up with a nice and working user script to do that, I'd be glad to steal it for SOUP.

Comment: @AstroCB: Thanks! A fix for [mse266852: Bar between “add a comment” and “show more comments” is inconsistent](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266852), loosely based on your script, is now included in the just released SOUP v1.20.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Great: thanks. It doesn't appear to be getting much traction over at MSO, so I don't see it happening officially anytime soon.

Comment: Regarding comment management: [bulk operations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238098/give-mods-bulk-operations-for-comments) might be doable by userscript?

Comment: @Raphael: Probably, but you'll need to find a mod with userscript skills to code and test it. I know there are a bunch, so it's doable, and I'd probably be happy to, ahem, borrow the code for SOUP if someone does write it (and it doesn't break the existing interface or have any other obvious issues, of course).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Since both flag and deletion API are exposed to any user (with enough rep) I'd thought you'd not need a mod account? (Note that "move to chat" is not a feature right now, anyway.) I'd be happy to test but I don't feel I'm qualified to write it.

Comment: @Raphael: Ah, I thought the request was about the mod queue, which, AIUI, works a bit differently from the usual question view. I suppose I could give it a try, and you can tell me if it works or not. :)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen No, it's about the usual comment list below posts. :) Let me know if you do!

Comment: How comes Stack Overflow doesn't implement this solutions in the official code?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei: [Sometimes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223601) they [do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234630). I am kind of hoping that some day, some SE dev will sit down and look through the SOUP source code for fixes to apply officially. The CSS fixes are particularly easy, most of them could just be copy-pasted directly into the appropriate SE style sheets (hint, hint!).

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen I know, that's why I asked. At least the css easy fixes

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I've a feature request. On an SE post, suppose a user posts a comment, and then edits it within the five minute window. Now unless you submit a new comment (below that edited comment) or force a page reload, you won't see that the comment has been edited. So, I request for a script that continuously checks whether any comment has been updated, and displays the updated comment. Is this within the scope of SOUP? Thank you!

Comment: @GaurangTandon: It definitely would be, if there was a practical way to do it with a user script without hammering the SE servers with continuous checks. I'm not sure there is, though. :( Also, in any case I'd recommend posting a feature request for that on [meta.se], if you haven't already. I try to make sure that every fix in SOUP has a bug report / feature request on meta, since the long term goal is to have SE actually fix all this stuff for everybody. Occasionally it even happens.

Comment: I added a new fix, which I proposed on GitHub a while back but didn't receive a response.

Answer (score 5):

## Known bugs

### Browser specific issues

#### Opera

Note: These issues mainly apply to older versions of the Opera browser.  Since version 15, Opera has switched to the the Blink rendering engine also used by Chrome, so some of these issues may be gone (but some of the Chrome-specific issues listed below may apply instead).  More testing is needed.

- Markdown editor hooks (e.g. [mse224533](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224533), [math11392](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11392), [boardgames1152](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1152), [french347](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/347)) sometimes fail to run on Opera, apparently due to a race condition where the editor gets initialized before SOUP has a chance to add the hook.  Reloading the edit page usually fixes the problem.
- The kluge used to monitor WebSocket messages on SE chat doesn't seem to work on old Opera versions, so SOUP falls back to polling for changes at ½ second intervals.  This works, but is less efficient.

#### Chrome

- The [mse154788](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154788/why-are-comments-overlapping-the-sidebar) / [stats1987](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1987/rendering-error-comments-with-mathjax-syntax-errors-overflow-their-boxes) fix in SOUP v1.22+ may sometimes [add spurious scroll bars to comments on Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240352/horizontal-scrollbar-for-comment-container).  This *should* hopefully be fixed in SOUP v1.24, but since I can't personally reproduce the bug, and since the underlying cause is uncertain (I suspect a bug in Chrome), it's hard to be sure.  If it still happens for you, please let me know!
- MathJax config fixes sometimes don't get applied on Chrome, apparently due to a race condition.  Reloading the page usually fixes it.  Investigating.

### Other compatibility issues

- SOUP does not work (at all) on the Scriptish user script extension for Firefox, version 0.1.11, because document.documentElement is not available at document-start.  Apparently, this is [a bug in Scriptish](https://github.com/scriptish/scriptish/issues/16) that has been fixed in [Scriptish 0.1.12](https://addons.mozilla.org/fi/firefox/addon/scriptish/versions/?page=1#version-0.1.12), but that version was [never properly approved for distribution on addons.mozilla.org](https://github.com/scriptish/scriptish/issues/239).  As Scriptish seems to have not been maintained since 2013, I recommend switching to another user script extension such as Greasemonkey.
- The [Dude, where's my cursor?](https://stackapps.com/questions/3894/dude-wheres-my-cursor) user script by balpha is incompatible with the [mso300679](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300679) fix as currently implemented in SOUP v1.36+, and may generate spurious warning dialogs about malformed HTML code.  These warnings are harmless, but potentially annoying.  (Thanks to Nathan Tuggy for the [report](https://stackapps.com/posts/comments/14863).)

## Bug reports

> **If you've found a bug in your SOUP, please post a comment below to notify me about it.**
>
> This includes any unwanted side effects or regressions due to changes in the SE codebase.

Comment: Not sure if this is necessarily a problem caused by the patch but using it seems to be a huge contributing factor in FF's memory leaks (at least in my case). This has caused problems for me since for a long time and I'm only now trying to keep Grease Monkey disabled. So far, memory usage is pretty low (~600MB) even after a day or two. It used to go up to and beyond 2.5GB in that same amount of time. And this is considering I keep 2 pinned tabs of SE sites, refreshing every 15 minutes (5 for SO). This might be for the GM team or something but just thought you should know.

Comment: @JeffMercado: Thanks for the notice, I'll try to look into it. If you have time, is there any chance you could test how the memory usage behaves with GM on but SOUP disabled?

Comment: GM is on. I'll let you know in a day or two how much of a change there is.

Comment: Back in v1.16 you patched [mse229797](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229797/you-are-here-but-wheres-here). The issue was [brought back up recently and fixed by SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278101/questions-link-almost-unreadable-when-active-on-meta). However, SE also changed the height of the hover background effect, which is different to the smaller height of active background enforced by SOUP. So if you remove the code from SOUP for that fix, everything will work properly.

Comment: Comparison: [No SOUP (default)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/x4diI.gif), vs [with SOUP (broken)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/duhNv.gif).

Comment: @angussidney: It's already removed from the devel branch. If I don't have time to make a whole new stable release this weekend, I'll backport the removal to the stable branch.

Comment: So after having GM on for 2 days, memory usage is still low. I'm going to restart FF with the script enabled.

Comment: @JeffMercado: Thanks! I'll try to run some tests myself, although I probably won't have time to do it for a few days at least.

Comment: I can't say this conclusively yet since I've had to restart a couple of times and couldn't have FF running as long, but I did notice just before resetting this morning (after about 1.5 days), memory usage was a little high.  (~1GB instead of ~700MB)  I'll have to retry the test again.

Comment: @JeffMercado: I tried to reproduce this issue, but after leaving half a dozen SE tabs pinned overnight and using `about:memory` to compare things before and after, I'm not seeing any obvious leakage. (In fact, the memory usage *dropped* by 60 MB or so overnight, presumably because Firefox ran a GC pass at some point.) Looking at your original report above, could you tell me what kind of pages you have pinned (front page / question page / chat? or just give URLs)? Also, you say you have them "refreshing every 15 minutes (5 for SO)"; how are you doing that? With an extension?

Comment: I have 3 tabs pinned, no others, maximized and the browser left on all day. Things tend to start to deteriorate after day 2. (1) Google Inbox (no reload), (2) gaming.SE Home (15min reload), (3) SO Home (5min reload). Tab reloading is done via [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/). I'm not watching `about:memory`, but memory usage in task manager.  Memory without it sits at 700MB. With, it rises to about 1GB after a day, 1.5GB after about two, then things start to fail at around 2.5GB usage.

Comment: HTML comments trigger the "Bad HTML that will be silently removed" warning, which is dumb, since they're *supposed* to be removed. The parser [doesn't actually support them directly](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120415/is-closing-html-comments-without-a-delimiter), so this is understandable, but an irritating glitch all the same.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: That's *not* supposed to happen, as long as the comments are correctly formatted (i.e. `<!-- some text here -->`). Can you show me a test case where that fails (like a post that gives the warning when edited, or some Markdown I can paste into the editor to trigger it)?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rlle.png for example, or I just footled around taking out one or two of the opening characters of a comment, putting them back in, and waiting until the warning showed up.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Alas, I still can't reproduce this myself. :( I do get the warning if I delete one or both of the opening dashes from the comment (which is appropriate, since it's not a valid comment without the dashes) and wait a few seconds for the popup to trigger, but it goes away (like it's supposed to) if I put the dashes back. To investigate further, could you check if you get any error messages with the prefix `mso300679 hook:` logged in your browser's developer console when this happens? Also, do you by any chance have any other user scripts installed that might be interfering here?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: I have a lot, but after a bit of tedious binary searching I narrowed to down to balpha's http://stackapps.com/questions/3894/dude-wheres-my-cursor (although I still don't know exactly how that interferes — there are no error messages). Sorry to bother you with a report that turned out bogus.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: That's actually *very* helpful, and I can see what's going wrong now. (SOUP isn't expecting anyone to call `MarkdownConverter.makeHtml()` in the background, especially not with intentionally mangled Markdown like *Dude, where's my cursor* does.) I'll list the incompatibility as a known bug for now, and will take a closer look later to see if I can somehow fix it.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen New bug: something in SOUP is making tag syntax inside tag warnings illegible on RPG.SE. See here: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7486/tag-appearance-in-our-tag-warnings-is-broken-cant-read-them. Seems to be a rule that turns links in tag warnings yellow (targets `body .message.message-warning a`) which would also be an issue on our site since our tag dialogs themselves are yellow.

Comment: @doppelgreener Thanks for the report. I'll take a closer look in a few hours when I get home. I don't *recall* there being anything in SOUP that should turn tags yellow, but some style might be getting applied where it shouldn't be.

Comment: In Microsoft Edge, the avatars appear in the wrong spot on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305886/why-isnt-comments-are-not-for-extended-discussion-the-case-on-meta). See https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rNik.png

Comment: @gparyani: Huh... I've no idea what might be causing that. I'll try to test that, but since I'm running Linux at home and don't have convenient access to a Windows box for testing, that may take a while. :/ Thanks for the report, anyway!

Comment: General question: do you prefer issues to be filed here as a comment, or on the Issues section in GitHub?

Comment: @gparyani: Either will work, but I guess the GitHub method scales a bit better as more issues get reported over time. At some point, I probably should copy all known issues over to GitHub and just direct people there. On the other hand, not everybody has a GitHub account, so...

Comment: SOUP adds a horizontal scrollbar to pages that include spoiler markup (Chrome 64, Windows 10). See this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60176/what-colour-was-the-no-theres-no-damn-bears-here) for example. It's the Spoiler `::before` element causing the width issue. Removing the `width: 100%` property seems to fix it, *or* you can assign `position: relative;` to the `.soup-spoiler` class. It seems the combination of width:100% and position:absolute (within the page positioning scope) makes the ::before element be the maximum width of the page itself... or something.

Comment: @doppelgreener: Thanks for the report. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce it (on Chrome 64 / Windows 7), but it's far from the first [mysterious](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240352) [scroll](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2380) [bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299196) [issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306254) on Chrome. I'll look into it. In the mean time, any chance you could send me a screenshot?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Sure! Screenshots here: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6667141#6667141

Comment: @doppelgreener: Oh, wait... yeah, I can reproduce *that*. I was looking in the wrong place for the scroll bar. :/ Anyway, yeah, your diagnosis seems correct, it's the `width: 100%` that's causing it. Will fix, thanks!

Comment: @doppelgreener: [Should be fixed in the development branch.](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/commit/4609dbbea0c1e9d8e8ba25e432ffce92a72911db)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Just updated my script to that development branch version; it looks fixed from my end. Good stuff.

Comment: Filed another GitHub issue: https://github.com/vyznev/soup/issues/49

Comment: Suspected bug: [Why is this suggested edit of a question title displaying peculiarly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352503/269301)

Comment: So I made some PRs recently to fix some bugs that cropped up in SOUP due to SE changes. It would be nice if you handled those.

Comment: @gparyani: I'll see about it. Honestly, in the last year and a half I've mostly lost my interest in maintaining SOUP in its current form, as I no longer believe that SE Inc's business model is long-term viable or aligned with the goal of creating an expert Q&A community. And I've also been kind of busy with my day job. But I'm still willing to remove broken fixes and make other similar minor updates, if I can find some time. And I haven't entirely ruled out the possibility of making SOUP 2.0 some day — although if I do, it'll probably be GNU AGPL licensed.

Comment: Horizontal scroll bar observed in Chrome 94.0.4606.81 with SOUP 1.56.2. (See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412439/8344060)

Answer (score 5):

## Change log

*The SOUP change log has grown too long for a StackApps post. You may [view it on GitHub](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) instead.*

Answer (score 5):

## Feature request

Please allow disabling of specific fixes; even a textbox that lets me add fix names per line would be helpful.

This would let me remove fixes I'd not want applied on a case by case basis. Sometimes, I want to make sure that a specific fix doesn't accidentally make it harder for me to understand another user's view on the site, and sometimes I don't agree with a fix (such as the 'accepted answer' unpinning fix, `mse178439`).

Comment: This isn't a bad idea. Perhaps a textbox that you can simply search something like `mse178439` (as opposed to having hundreds of checkboxes to chose from). Typing `mse178` would bring up all the matches for `mse178###`, and a toggle-switch that lets your turn this on or off. The way to access this is to place a link in the site's footer, similar to how [Advanced Flagging US](https://github.com/SOBotics/AdvancedFlagging/blob/master/dist/AdvancedFlagging.user.js) does.

Answer (score 2):

### SOUP for Chrome Install Test

[The owner of SOUP](https://stackapps.com/users/10283/ilmari-karonen) made an install guide in [a comment on this post](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup/7018?noredirect=1#comment15512_7018).

I'll include it here for more attention, but if you upvote this, you should upvote that comment as well.

> Just for clarity, note that [the official SOUP Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-overflow-unofficial/bagdnnmjfkaolcegcgeohpboeocfalpj) does not display this notice. The easiest way to tell that the SOUP extension is installed is by the presence of the grayed-out SOUP icon in the Chrome toolbar (unless you've hidden it). You can also press F12 to open Developer Tools, and switch to the Console tab; with SOUP installed, this tab should contain (at least) the lines `soup injecting fixes`, `soup init complete`, `soup setup complete` and `soup JS fixes applied`.

[image: Image of console logs]

### SOUP for Chrome<sup><sup>Alpha</sup></sup> Install Test

You can see if SOUP is installed by scrolling to the bottom of the page.

[image: Alpha install test]

There is hidden text saying "Successfully installed SOUP!".

Comment: Just for clarity, note that [the official SOUP Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-overflow-unofficial/bagdnnmjfkaolcegcgeohpboeocfalpj) does not display this notice. The easiest way to tell that the SOUP extension is installed is by the presence of the grayed-out SOUP icon in the Chrome toolbar (unless you've hidden it). You can also press F12 to open Developer Tools, and switch to the Console tab; with SOUP installed, this tab should contain (at least) the lines `soup injecting fixes`, `soup init complete`, `soup setup complete` and `soup JS fixes applied`.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen [I added this to my post.](http://stackapps.com/revisions/7018/3)