# Load answers to a question with review-like wrapper HTML

Tags: support, discussion, answers, scripts, ajax

I'm trying to implement [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/172931/please-put-answers-underneath-questions-in-close-review-queue/212479#212479) in [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch), but I'm having trouble figuring out a good way to actually load the answers.

- I can just load the full question page ([like this one, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980999/what-does-multicore-assembly-language-look-like)) and extract the answers off of it with jQuery.  However, this gives me a bunch on non-functional UI elements (like tabs and vote buttons) that I don't really want, and it also ends up re-running any scripts embedded on the page.  Surprisingly, despite those issues, it still seems to more or less work, but I really don't like it.
- I can use an API [/questions/{ids}/answers](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions) query with [filter=withbody](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) to get the answer bodies in a JSON wrapper ([example](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/980999/answers?site=stackoverflow&filter=withbody)).  This has kind of the opposite problem — I *only* get the HTML for the answer body, and would have to manually reconstruct all the surrounding "wrapper" HTML based on the metadata in the JSON response.  I don't really like this option either, if only because I don't like my user scripts full of hardcoded HTML code.
- Finally, the undocumented(?) URL used to fetch the question previews for the close-as-duplicate popup, `/posts/popup/close/search-originals/1?q=/questions/{id}`, gives me almost *exactly* the kind of HTML I want ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/popup/close/search-originals/19942890?q=/questions/980999/what-does-multicore-assembly-language-look-like)).  Alas, it seems to only work for questions that are actually eligible for being marked as duplicates, i.e. those that have at least one *accepted or upvoted* answer.

So, does anyone know of a convenient way (officially documented or not) to load the full answers to a question, including an HTML wrapper similar to what would normally be shown on the close vote review page ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2859626))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I ended up using in SOUP 1.10 is the first one listed above — loading the full question page and stripping it down to match the review interface.  Here's the core of the [actual code](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/a073d6490c10f66274fd5f9beee8a7028c8cdc3d/SOUP.user.js#L520-L547):

```javascript
var injectAnswers = function ( html ) {
    // new cleaner parsing!
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString( html, 'text/html' );
    var rawAnswers = doc.querySelectorAll('.answer');  // XXX: don't use .getElementsByClassName(), loop below needs a static NodeList!
    var answers = $('<div>'), n = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < rawAnswers.length; i++) {
        if ( document.getElementById( rawAnswers[i].id ) ) continue;
        answers[0].appendChild( rawAnswers[i] );
        n++;
    }
    answers = answers.children();

    // mangle the answer wrappers to look like the review page before injecting them
    answers.find('.votecell button, .post-menu > *, .comments, .comments-link').remove();
    answers.find('.votecell .js-vote-count').after( function () {
        return '<div class="fs-caption fc-black-500 ta-center">vote' + ( this.textContent.trim() == 1 ? '' : 's' ) + '</div>';
    } );

    // inject answers into the review page
    var header = $('<div id="answers-header"><div class="subheader answers-subheader"><h2></h2></div></div>');
    header.find('h2').text( n + ( shown ? ' Other' : '') + ' Answer' + ( n == 1 ? '' : 's' ) );
    header.insertAfter( question );
    answers.insertAfter( header );
};
```

Here, `url` is the normal URL of the question (obtained from the link in the question title), `question` is the question div (with class "question") on the review page DOM and `shown` is the number of answers already shown on the review page (e.g. when reviewing an answer).