# Comment Separator Fix

Tags: script, comments, style

## This fix is now included in the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP) v1.20.0](https://stackapps.com/a/4559/25923)

## About

We have this nicely formatted toolbar with all of the moderation tools we need below questions:

[image: SE Toolbar]

So, why is it that the separator that goes along with the [new comment format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235255/proposed-tweak-to-comment-ui-for-long-threads) looks like this?

[image: New comment styling]

This is a simple fix that removes the extra space between the separator and the comment buttons and makes the separator the same color as the standard separator.

On [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/), it looks like this:

[image: Fixed comment styling]

As an added bonus, it will match the styling of the default toolbar for each particular site because it uses the SE-defined class for the toolbar separators.

For example, [Meta Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com/) uses this design for toolbars:

[image: MSE Toolbar]

There are no separators, which adheres to MSE's design. However, the new comment format uses separators anyway:

[image: New comment design on MSE]

Because this script utilizes the built-in classes for toolbars on each site, it will adhere to its design principles:

[image: Fixed MSE design]

This script was inspired by [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266852/bar-between-add-a-comment-and-show-more-comments-is-inconsistent) on [Meta Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/).

## Download

You can download the script from [Greasy Fork](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/3642-comment-separator-fix) ([Direct Link](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/3642-comment-separator-fix/code/Comment%20Separator%20Fix.user.js)) or [view the source code](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/3642-comment-separator-fix/code).

## Installation

See the [script](/questions/tagged/script) tag wiki for details on userscript installation.

## History

See the [Greasy Fork changelog](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/3642-comment-separator-fix/versions).

## Contact

Please post bug reports or feature requests on this page as an answer or comment.

Comment: **Version 1.1.3** (took a bit of tinkering there) fixes a bug that caused a separator to be displayed even though no comments overflowed. This bug was caused by the way that SE structured the inclusion of the separator.

Comment: **Version 1.2.1** fixes a bug that caused the separator to remain after `show comments` was clicked.

Comment: **Version 2.0** has been entirely rewritten in a way that should force the script to act in a way that is compliant with SE standards, thus negating the need for previous workarounds and deeming this (tentatively) the final version.

Comment: **Version 3.1.0** fixes the only known bug whereby new comments loaded over AJAX did not have the separator.