# A userscript collects all useful userscript?

Tags: discussion

Although I can code, I don't really want to code if it's not relevant to my work. I love using userscripts, but spending time digging the repository makes me tired. Do you have a "super"-userscript that combines many little ones? Something like [F.B. Purity](http://www.fbpurity.com/) for Facebook? Thank you.

Comment: you need better organization of your scripts. taking time to properly document and file scripts can save a lot of time in the future.

Comment: Another script is [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/29559).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same feeling last year, so I started collecting all sorts of little interface fixes into a single script that I called the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch), or SOUP for short.

Of course, SOUP is still very much a work in progress, and always will be.  If you find something missing from it, I'm always happy to receive suggestions (and even happier to receive code; hint, hint!).

I do tend to take a somewhat conservative approach with SOUP, only including things that I'm fairly sure that over 99% of people would want (and which few, if any people would be likely to seriously object to), since they currently all come in one "take it or leave it" package.  That said, I do think it could be a good idea to introduce more customizability and optional features into SOUP in the future, either through some kind of control panel, or directly by injecting custom (but non-obtrusive) interface elements into the SE design to control the features.

Comment: Have you tried [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/29559)? How does it compare to yours?

Comment: @Ooker: I have, although I don't use it actively. There's some overlap between SOUP and SOX, but mostly they complement each other. The big difference is that SOX does have a menu for toggling features on and off, so it can and does incorporate more controversial changes to the SE user interface. SOUP is meant to be more of an "install and forget" thing; it has no config menu for optional features, and probably won't be getting one now that SOX exists and fills that gap. Anyway, SOUP and SOX *should* be usable together; if you find an incompatibility, please report it and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: As how I understand SOUP means as a *fix* for the site, and SOX as a *modification* of it. Is that correct? Because I think having a menu is very important for users to know what it does

Comment: Pretty much, yeah.